# unexpected successful copy based on strlen

Tags: c++, string, buffer, memcpy

I was reviewing my skills with pointers and buffer in C++. I tried the code below and everything works fine. No leaks, no crash, nothing.

To be honest I didn't expect this.

When I call `char* buf2 = new char[strlen(buf)]` I didn't expect `srlen(buf)` returning the right size. I always thought that `strlen`
needs a NULL terminated string to work. Here it is not the case so why it is working this code?

```
        int main(){
             const char* mystr = "mineminemine";
             char* buf = new char[strlen(mystr)];
             memcpy(buf, mystr, strlen(mystr));

             char* buf2 = new char[strlen(buf)];
             memcpy(buf2, buf, strlen(buf));

             delete[] buf2;
             delete[] buf;
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's called undefined behavior - the program appears working but you can't rely on that.

When memory is allocated there happens a null character somewhere that is close enough to the start of the buffer and the program can technically access all memory between that null character and the start of the buffer so you don't observe a crash.

You can't rely on that behavior. Don't write code like that, always allocate enough space to store the terminating null character.

Comment: just one more observation to add - you must allocate new char[strlen(buf)+1]; for a null terminating character

Comment: Hi Ulterior. The main point of my question was about the fact that everything works fine without 'strlen(buf)+1'. Cheers AFG

Comment: Is it really "undefined"?  It is dependent on the contents of memory but I don't think there's anything happening in strlen that isn't defined behaviour.

EDIT: of course, I'm wrong.  Out-of-bounds array access is the quintessential example of undefined behaviour.  Doh.

Answer (score 0):

Consider another way to do the same thing:

```
 int main(){
          std::string mystr = "mineminemine";
          std::string mystr2 = mystr;
 }
```

Internally you have a buffer with a null terminating character added. When you copy a standard string you don't have to worry about keeping track of the start and end of the buffer.

Now considering the lifetime of the strings these two variables are declared on the stack and destroyed when main goes out of scope (e.g. terminationa). If you need strings to be shared amongst objects and you do not necessarily know when they will be destroyed I recommend considering using boost shared pointers.